# My firebase project is trying to deploy to a different project

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I've been building a lot of small projects, and I copy past my base code and modify it from there.

I've done the same for this current project I am working on but I am having a weird issue. It is saying it tries to deploy to a different project so I keep getting errors (500 if I want to deploy the whole project, 403 if I try to deploy only functions).

This project is it trying to deploy to doesn't even exist anymore.

I've changed my firebase config files with the the config details and I've checked like 10 times that I am using the correct details for the new project.
I've also edited `.firebasesrc` and edited the `default` field to be that of this new project I am working on, but everything is the same.

It what file does firebase look in to decided where to deploy to?
Whenever I try to deploy, it says deploying to "name-of-my-previous-project". If I try to find this name, I can't find it at all in my project. No where.
Is it going by some cached files maybe? How do I delete them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in a file called ".firebaserc" in the directory where you initially ran `firebase init`.  You can change and override the current project using the instructions in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#use_aliases).